# Абсолютно позиционированный элемент внутри блока с фиксированной шириной при наличии вертикального скролла

Tags: html, css

Имеется блок с фиксированной шириной и высотой, в него может быть вложено несколько элементов которые будут создавать вертикальную прокрутку. При этом в каждом элементе находится кнопка, при клике на которую вызывается тултип, который выходит за границу блока и создает горизонтальную прокрутку. Можно ли сделать, чтобы он располагался поверх блока, как без overflow-y, но сохранением прокрутки.

```css
.block {
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #ff9199;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.row {
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #c8c8c8;
}

.row + .row {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.button-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 20px;
}

.button {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ddf58f;
}

.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: #00c50d;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="button-wrapper">
      <div class="button"></div>
      <div class="tooltip">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
  <div class="row"></div>
</div>
```